# Gnome shell crashes at startup

Tags: gnome, startup, error-handling

Every time i boot my ubuntu gnome 16.10 [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8D9YZ.png) message comes up even though my gnome shell runs without any problems. Any ideas what's wrong with my pc?

Comment: Gnome shell 3.20? Are you running gnome 3.20? Did you add a third party repository?

Comment: Yes its the gnome 3.20 shell. What kind of third party repostirory? @xangua